# Physically delay USB connection on startup

Tags: usb, boot

I've been trying to search for a physical adapter that would accept a USB (not a flash drive, but a software dongle) and connect into a USB port that would literally delay the pass-through of the device to the port.

Specifically, the computer/BIOS is set to boot to the USB drive first, which I must emphasize **cannot be changed**. Also the goal is to leave the device plugged in because the computer powers on and off regularly and the port is located in a difficult place to reach frequently. The dongle is causing start up issues since it is not a bootable drive. I need a physical device to prevent power and/or data connection when it receives power with the PC is booting. Or some other creative way to get around this.

Comment: What exactly is a "software dongle" in this context if not a flash storage device?

Comment: http://www.safenet-inc.com/products/software-rights-management/sentinel-hasp-hl/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the most sensible solution would be to get a extension cable, and a USB hub with switches for each port - that way, you can get the USB drive in reach *and* switch off the port when not in use. I can't think of anything that would delay connection, without a lot of soldering an a microcontroller.

Answer (score -1):

With electronic components it is not so difficult to achieve: one or two transistors, one capacitor and few resistances are enough. Just search for "Dealy circuit" in google and you'll get lot of examples. If still interested, I can calculate the values of the elements for you.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Since I cannot  comment anywhere, what should I do? Shall I calculate the values of the components to reach the "answer status"? Should I delete the answer?